# IntelliJ IDEA debug configuration: bash scripting to limit cpu/bandwidth

Tags: java, intellij-idea, software-quality, bandwidth-throttling

I need to limit the CPU and bandwidth of my application for testing purposes during the development process and wrote a small bash script wrapper around the java command, but I'm not sure how I can integrate this approach with IDEA's run/debug configuration.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Usage: javalimit [CPU Percentage] [download in kbps] [upload in kbps] [normal java args]"
    echo "Required packages: trickle, cpulimit"
fi

CPU_PERCENTAGE=$1
DOWNLOAD_KBPS=$2
UPLOAD_KBPS=$3

shift 3


trickle -s -d $DOWNLOAD_KBPS -u $UPLOAD_KBPS java $@

TRICKLED_PID=$!

cpulimit --limit=$CPU_PERCENTAGE --pid=$TRICKLED_PID
```

My first failed approach for IDEA integration was

Statically set the cpu/down/up, removed shift

Copied my java folder to a new one, renamed java command, symbolic linked my script to bin/java

Told IDEA to use this JRE config - Crashed

Any insights on a better way to approach this problem would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best solution would be to use the **Remote Debug** as I've [suggested in the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661118/debug-shell-script-in-intellij-9/3661387#3661387).